# open DMTP read custom event packet server side

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement in server open DMTP a new custom event packet, but I really don't know where to start. I read most of the code, but I can't realize where to put the saving part of my custom data. I downloaded also the code of open GTS, but it apparently does not "store" custom data. Can anyone help me? Give me some indication where to start? Sadly there's no developer documentation.